# function try block. An interesting example

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following C++ program

```
struct str
{
       int mem;
       str()
       try
          :mem(0)
       {
               throw 0;
       }
       catch(...)
       {
       }
};

int main()
{
       str inst;
}
```

The catch block works, i.e. the control reaches it, and then the program crashes. I can't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Additional answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921250/constructor-as-a-function-try-block-exception-aborts-program

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once the control reaches the end of the catch block of function-try-block of a constructor, the exception is automatically rethrown. As you don't catch it further in main(), terminate() is called.
Here is an interesting reading: http://www.drdobbs.com/184401316

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it rethrown only in constructor or in other functions too?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: You're welcome ;) Only in constructor. That all is explained very well in the link above.

Comment: The same thing happens if you use a function-try-block in a destructor.  The article mentions that too.

Comment: @nobar: Yes, that's right. I was answering to "Is it rethrown only in constructor or in other functions too?" to make it clear it doesn't happen with any function having a function try block. But yes, in general, it's constructors and destructors with function try blocks that have this 'automatic rethrow' behavior.