# Difference between function and block scope in C?

Tags: c, scope

What is the difference between block scope and function scope in C? I was told that any variables declared inside curly brackets counts as being in block scope, but when we declare a function, it starts and closed with a curly bracket. I'm confused.

Comment: You are not, hopefully someone will give you a complete answer, I can't know because It's late in my country.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Lashane: The question is clear enough. The C standard defines the terms "function scope" and "block scope"; see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.1.

Comment: @KeithThompson ok, so question is "Im banned from google, I don't wanna read books, but I like posting questions on SO"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933814/difference-between-local-scope-and-function-scope

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C language *function scope* is a formal term that describes scope of *labels*. A label is visible in the entire function, regardless of where in that function it is declared. Labels are the only entities that have that unusual property, hence the need for special kind of scope for them. Nothing else can have *function scope*.

Variables cannot have function scope. All variables declared locally always have *block scope*. The outermost pair of `{ ... }` that envelops the entire function is also a block.