# Throwing exception in function

Tags: c++, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between try-catch syntax for function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756931/difference-between-try-catch-syntax-for-function)

There is this code:

```
int fun() try
{
    throw 1;
    return 2;
}
catch(int){
    return 1;
}

int fun2(){
    try{
        throw 1;
        return 2;
    }
    catch(int){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

What is purpose of keeping whole function body in try block and are these two definitions of functions different according to try..catch block?

Comment: What is your question? Please clarify.

Comment: It's about keeping body of function in try..catch block (first function in example). What is this is used for and what is the difference according to second function in example?

Comment: Those two functions are essentially identicial, it's simply relying on the fact that much like all c++ constructs (if/while etc) you don't need to specify braces if you're just doing one thing at that scope level.  That being said, the first example is ugly as hell and I wouldn't do it.

Comment: `fun()` is so ugly and not fun.

Comment: @Benj: That's not true; a function-body can only be either a function-try-block (like the first example), or a compound-statement (i.e. a bunch of statements surrounded by `{}` like the second example). Something like `int fun() return 0;` with no braces is not allowed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You're quite correct, my apologies.  I've always thought it was a bit nasty so I've never tried all the permutations...